# pywinauto handling multiple popups (control panel example)

Tags: pywinauto

I am trying to automate adapter setting in windows client.

```
I have written pywinauto(python) code to open till Ethernet Properties
```

after that I am not able to proceed.

```
Process finished with exit code 1

from __future__ import print_function
from pywinauto import Application

# Open "Control Panel"
Application().start('control.exe')
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path='explorer.exe', title='Control Panel')
# Go to "Programs"
app.window(title="Control Panel").NetworkandInternetHyperlink.invoke()
app.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=0.5, timeout=30, usage_interval=1.0)
#app.window(title='Control Panel').ProgramsHyperlink.invoke()
#app.wait_cpu_usagce_lower(threshold=0.5, timeout=30, usage_interval=1.0)

# Go to "Installed Updates"
app.window(title='Network and Internet').child_window(title='View network status and tasks', control_type='Hyperlink').invoke()
app.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=0.5, timeout=30, usage_interval=1.0)
app.window(title="Network and Sharing Center").ChangeadaptersettingsHyperlink.invoke()

list_box = app.NetworkConnections.FolderViewListBox

# list all updates
items = list_box.descendants(control_type='ListItem')
all_updates = [item.window_text() for item in items]
print('\nAll updates ({}):\n'.format(len(all_updates)))
print(all_updates)

# list updates from "Microsoft Windows" group only
app.window(title='Network Connections').Ethernet0Hyperlink.invoke()
app.window(title="Ethernet0 Status").PropertiesHyperlink.invoke()
app.Ethernet0Properties.Cancel.click() >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>HITTING ERROR
```

==========================================================

## OUTPUT

[image]

`E:\ProgramFiles_64\Python\python.exe C:/Users/aerwa/PycharmProjects/Akhil_practice/venv/Scripts/Control_Panel.py`

All updates (3):

```
['Bluetooth Network Connection', 'Ethernet0', 'Npcap Loopback Adapter']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\ProgramFiles_64\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 256, in __resolve_control
    criteria)
  File "E:\ProgramFiles_64\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 458, in wait_until_passes
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aerwa/PycharmProjects/Akhil_practice/venv/Scripts/Control_Panel.py", line 29, in <module>
    app.Ethernet0Properties.Cancel.click()
  File "E:\ProgramFiles_64\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 362, in __getattribute__
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "E:\ProgramFiles_64\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 259, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
  File "E:\ProgramFiles_64\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 436, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\ProgramFiles_64\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 220, in __get_ctrl
    ctrl = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**ctrl_criteria))
  File "E:\ProgramFiles_64\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 84, in find_element
    elements = find_elements(**kwargs)
  File "E:\ProgramFiles_64\Python\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 303, in find_elements
    elements = findbestmatch.find_best_control_matches(best_match, wrapped_elems)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The problem might be that properties dialog is in different process. Please try to re-connect by title.

Comment: Thanks @VasilyRyabov, now it is working after reconnecting.

app2=Application().connect(title="Ethernet0 Properties")

I have one more question

If you see my attached image, Ethernet0 Properties window.

1. How to select "Authentication"

Comment: `app2.Ethernet0_Properties.TabControlNetworking.select("Authentication")` probably